# Retina "@2x" graphics incorrectly being used on standard-def display (using Snow Leopard / Xcode 4.2 )

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard

I am developing a Mac app using Xcode 4.2 in OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard.

My Xcode project contains, in the same folder and at exactly-doubled dimensions:

`image.png`
`image@2x.png`

I use the [Apple-recommended](https://developer.apple.com/resources/high-resolution/) -[NSImage imageNamed:] method to load the correct resource depending on the user's screen type:

`[NSImage imageNamed:@"image"];`

However, when I run the app on my non-retina 1440x900 display, the "@2x" version of the image is displayed. I get a 100x100 image when it should be a 50x50.

The same code works fine to deliver both standard-def and retina images, depending, when I run the app in 10.7 Lion (switching between standard and HiDPI modes).

I've thus far been unable to get Snow Leopard HiDPI (720x450) mode to work. But it still should be displaying the standard-def image when I use my standard-def display.

Is there a limitation of either Snow Leopard or Xcode 4.2 that causes this to work incorrectly? If so, how do you release an app that has a Deployment Target of 10.6 but still also has retina graphics support?

Comment: Is the normal resolution image added to your Resources? (inspect the bundled package)

Comment: @DrummerB When I "Show Package Contents" on my app (product) I see a single `image.tiff` file rather than the two .png files. Currently in Snow Leopard, can't Quicklook to see the various images in that .tiff...

Comment: Photoshop is only showing one layer, the `@2x` version. Both images are included in Target > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources.

Comment: Does Xcode 4.2 actually support creating retina Mac apps? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @pkamb Did you resolve this issue?  I also have the retina images being shown on my normal resolution screen.  It seems the 2x retina image order is incorrect when the tiff is generated.  Also disabling the "Combine High Resolution Artwork" did nothing.  Using Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.6.1

Comment: @Luke did you delete the .tiff file that may have been previously created? I had to set `Combine High-Res Artwork` to NO, *then* delete the previous .tiffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if Snow Leopard or Xcode 4.2 cannot properly combine High Resulotion Artwork into a single `.tiff` file?

Set `Combine High Resolution Artwork` to `NO` in your Target's Build Settings.

IMPORTANT: I then additionally needed to manually delete the previously created .tiffs from my app's bundle. `-[NSImage imageNamed:]` prefers the single .tiff to the 2 .pngs, so it will use the .tiff file if it finds it. Make sure it doesn't.

[image: Combine High Resolution Artwork: NO!]

Comment: Disabling this setting doesn't work for me.  Using Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.6.1.  Viewing the app bundle is shows no tiff image files.